# Why is this IF block not being entered after checking against an NSManagedObject boolean property?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, validation, ios4, nsmanagedobject

```
NSLog(@"move report - %@", [eventToArchive valueForKey:@"archived"]);
if (![eventToArchive valueForKey:@"archived"]) {
   ....
```

The above code block is NEVER being entered, even though NSLog returns

```
move report - 0
```

Every single time it runs?

Do I need to do something like,

```
if (![NSNumber numberWithBool:[eventToArchive valueForKey:@"archived"]]) {
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
if (![[eventToArchive valueForKey:@"archived"] boolValue])
```

boolValue works on `NSString`s and `NSNumber`s so if the archived property of eventToArchive is a BOOL, Key Value Coding will automatically convert that into a `NSNumber` for you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the conditional block is never entered is that -valueForKey: returns an `id`, which is to say a pointer. You're using it as though it were a BOOL, however, so the only way you'll ever enter that block is if -valueForKey: returns nil.

Your log statement prints "0" as the value because you used the object format specifier, `%@`, which expects a pointer and prints a description of the object that the pointer points to. You're probably giving it a NSNumber*, and it's properly printing the value represented by that object.

The preceding two answers are correct in pointing out that you should use the -boolValue method to get a BOOL value from the NSNumber that you get from -valueForKey:.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'archived' is a boolean property on a subclass of NSManagedObject you need to do;

```
if(![eventToAcrhive.archived boolValue]) {
    // not archived
}
```